# VBA Excel : Show the zero in left on mobile number

Tags: excel, vba, mobile, numbers, zero

I'm working on a project with VBA Excel, and I have a problem with mobile number.
When I insert the mobile number for example : 0762....... on excel we can see just 762...... without zero on the left.
How can I do that ?

This is a part of my script :

```
 If MsgBox("Confirmez-vous l’insertion de ce nouveau contact ?", vbYesNo, "Demande de confirmation d’ajout") = vbYes Then

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1 'Pour placer le nouvel enregistrement à la première ligne de tableau non vide

    MsgBox i

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("A" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("B" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("C" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("D" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox4.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("E" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("H" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox8.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("F" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox4.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("I" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox9.Value




End If
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add ' in front of it or change cell format to text.

Comment: have you tried the format function? Format(VALUE,"0000000000")

Comment: You can play around with formatting so that it always shows that leading zero but I imagine as these are dialing digits you should treat as text anyways so that it preserves any leading 0's. So agreed with @cyboashu to prepend with quote or format as text.

Comment: I also suggest that you refactor your code somehow, using some loops and arrays. This not only improves readability, it also helps avoid errors. Notice, for example, that in the line before the last line, you are overwriting on `G & i` twice...

Comment: Yes I know, I'm trying to get the result of two ComboBox in one cell on excel, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a format on the cells like this:

```
Sheets("Reservations").Range("I" & i).NumberFormat = "00 00 00 00 00"
```